# Solving the Dirichlet problem using conformal maps

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been tasked with using conformal maps to find solutions to the Dirichlet problem on various regions given the solution $u(x,y) = y$ on the strip $\{x + iy \mid 0 \leq y \leq 1\}$ satisfying $u(x, 0) = 0, u(x, 1) = 1$.

The first two (of five) regions are:

$U = \{z\mid r_1 \leq |z| \leq r_2\}, u(z)=0$ when $|z| = r_1, u(z) = 1$ when $|z| = r_2$,

$U=\{z\mid Im(z) \geq 0\}, u(x,0)=0$ when $x > 0,  u(x,0)=1$ when $x <0$.

How do I proceed to solve this sort of question? I cannot even see where to begin. I feel as though I'm somehow meant to find conformal maps from the various $U$'s to the given strip, but I cannot figure out how I'm meant to find those.

I've deliberately not asked about all the parts, because I do want to do this question. I just feel as though I'm missing an obvious trick that's stopping me from getting anywhere.